# php preg_replace for text start with *. and end with \r or \n

Tags: php, regex

i have 2 text string in php and i want to change them to html tags

first :

```
*.some text
* some text
```

and second :

```
#.sometext
# sometext
```

i want to change the first string that start with `'*.' or '* '` to `<li>` and end with `'\r'` or `'\n'` to `</li>`

and i want to change the second string that start with `'#.' or '# '` to `<ol>` and end with `'\r'` or `'\n'` to `</ol>`

I wrote this regex code but not work:

```
$regex1 = "#([*.])(.*)([\n])#e";
$text = preg_replace($regex1,"('<li>$2</li>')",$text);

$regex2 = "#([#.])(.*)([\n])#e";
$text = preg_replace($regex2,"('<ol>$2</ol>')",$text);
```

what should i do?

thanks a lot

Comment: thanks to comment my friend.but i wrote many of tags and just these to tags are incomplete.if i write these two,it'll finished.

Comment: @Vyktor, He's not parsing html. He's parsing something like Markdown, which can be parsed by regexs much better than html.

Comment: @Vyktor it's not DOM-style markup.  How are you supposed to parse it with DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend quite a few changes to your code, which I'll explain below.

First the code:

```
<?php
$text = "
first :

*.some text
* some text

and second :

#.sometext
# sometext
";

$regex1 = "#\*(.| )(.*?)\n#";
$text = preg_replace($regex1,"<li>$2</li>\n",$text);

$regex2 = "#\#(.| )(.*?)\n#";
$text = preg_replace($regex2,"<ol>$2</ol>\n",$text);

echo $text;
```

and the output

```
first :

<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>

and second :

<ol>sometext</ol>
<ol>sometext</ol>
```

Changes:

- You don't need to  use the `e` modifier in the regex
- In order to match `*.` and `*`, just specify `*` (escaped to `\*`, and an OR condition for `.` (escaped to `\.`) and .
- Use non-greedy version of `.*`, i.e. `.*?` so you only eat the least possible text.

PS: This probably isn't what you wanted (ol has this structure: `<ol><li>...</li><li>...</li></ol>`, but I wrote the code to your question's spec. You should be able to modify this.

Comment: thanks a lot.'*.' '* ' is works right.but '#.' is not right.its for <ol><li>...</li><li>.... . how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$str=<<<STR
abc
*.some text
* some text
def
STR;

echo preg_replace('/[\r\n]+<\/li>/i',"</li>",preg_replace('/\*[\.\s](.*)$/im',"<li>$1</li>",$str));
```

The above will output:

```html
abc
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
def
```

Similar change can be made to accomplish your second requirement.

The reason I use two regular expressions, is that in case your string looks like

```
$str=<<<STR
abc
*.some text
* some text
STR;
```

There will be no last-newline, so the last line may not be matched. So I use `m` modifier, and `$` to match every end-of-line.

But testing result shows that using only `$` will end up like this:

```html
abc
<li>some text
</li>
<li>some text</li>
```

So to avoid this, I added another regex to fix `[newline]</li>`.